# How to edit fields by choosing what to be edited and leaving the rest untouched

Tags: sql, navicat

I have to edit a all fields of a column. So far it is easy :D , but the problem is that the fields contains text and numbers. And I do need to replace the text only and leave the numbers untouched. What is more the text is in unicode which is making the task even harder lol. I tried to use this query but without success ..

```
UPDATE table_name SET field = REPLACE(field, ' ', 'My text')
```

Comment: Oracle/SQL Server/MySQL?

Comment: Do you know the difference between IDE/Server?

Comment: I know what ide is but i am not sure about which of the server meanings you reffer to

Comment: How do you develop not knowing which **RDBMS** you use?

Comment: It is too long story mate .. anyway thank you for trying to help me I do appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Oracle/Postgresql` you can use `REGEX_REPLACE` to replace `non-digit`:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET field = regexp_replace( field, '[^[:digit:]]', null ) ;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f645e/1/0)**</kbd>